# C - Passing by value in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I seem to be having a very strange issue in running a program with Visual Studio C++ 2010. Here is the (very simplified) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void recieve(double, double);
void simple_pass();

void recieve(double x, double y)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
}

void main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    simple_pass();
}

void simple_pass()
{
    recieve (0.25, 0.25);
    recieve (0.25, 0.75);
    recieve (0.75, 0.5);
}
```

When printing the values, x is always 0 and y is something greater than a billion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` is for ints, `%lf` is for doubles.

Most compilers would give you a warning for that these days...

Comment: `%f`, not `%lf`, since `%lf` in `printf` in C90 won't work. VS probably uses the old C89.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your format specifier used with the `printf` command. Simply change `%d` to `%lf` and the code is good to go.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void recieve(double, double);
void simple_pass();

void recieve(double x, double y)
{
    printf("%lf %lf\n", x, y);
}

void main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    simple_pass();
}

void simple_pass()
{
    recieve (0.25, 0.25);
    recieve (0.25, 0.75);
    recieve (0.75, 0.5);
}
```